# Serving a local file in an ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, httphandler

Let's say I have a file located at `C:\foo\bar.js` and I want to include this file in an ASP.NET MVC website that is, obviously, hosted on the same machine.

This doesn't work:

```
<script src="C:\foo\bar.js"></script>
```

And neither does this:

```
<script src="file:///C:/foo/bar.js"></script>
```

The above two lines do not make sense either since they would look at the client's folder, not the server's folder.

So how can I serve this file from an ASP.NET MVC Controller (in the controller, I have the string value of the path of the local physical file i.e. `C:\foo\bar.js`) to a View?  Maybe something with an HttpHandler?

Comment: FYI: You might come across browser security issues when doing this. But then, if you're serving a webpage that relies on files being in a particular place on the users disk...

Comment: No, the files will not be on the users' disk; the files that I will serve will be on the machine hosting the site, but not in the virtual directory so they are not exposed through the web server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: This solution is assuming that the js file is not part of the web app.  If it is, you should probably be using Url.Content or ResolveClientUrl instead..

You should be able to link to a controller action Url in your script tag:

```
<script src="/ControllerName/GetJavascriptFile"></script>
```

...and have an action like::

```
public ActionResult GetJavascriptFile() {
   string mp = @"C:\foo\bar.js";
   return File(mp, "text/javascript");
}
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(VS.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file%28VS.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Why the detour through a controller?

Comment: Maybe I misread.. but it sounds like the script file is not part of the web application. Otherwise including a script should be trivial.

Comment: That was the impression I got as well, hence the +1.  It seemed like the OP was asking how to include a file that's not actually exposed by the web server.

Comment: Yes, both markt and David are correct; The files that I want to serve are not part of the web application, and thus not exposed through the web server.

Comment: @Andreas: Why are you wanting to include a JavaScript file that's not part of the web application?

Comment: @Schnapple: Because these files will be added through another external service, and it's completely decoupled from the web application.  So the files will be in a repository kind of, and the web application will need to access it and serve them in a page.

Comment: @markt: Thanks for your answer; using the `Controller.File` class, I managed to do what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've been doing it is - suppose you have a folder called `Scripts` off of the root (so, parallel to `Controllers`, `Models`, etc.) and you store the JavaScript files in it, you can use this:

```
<script 
 src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jQuery-1.3.2.js")%>" 
 type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

(split onto multiple lines to make it easier to read)

This is assuming your question is how to link to the location of the `.js` include files, but a similar trick can be applied to any content files (i.e., plugin installers or whatnot)

Comment: The problem is that the files that I want to serve are not part of the virtual directory containing the site.